# Issue with booting/rebooting behavior when using a bootable SD Card

Tags: boot, grub2, sd-card

So, here's what I have:

- A bootable **SD Card**, with a minimal Ubuntu installation.
- A bootable **USB stick**, with exactly the same filesystem image.
- A Shuttle PC (much like the XS35V2 Digital Signage Media Player [seen here](http://us.shuttle.com/Models.aspx)).

The Shuttle PC has no internal storage at all, it relies entirely on bootable media, the GRUB partition is contained within the SD card and the USB stick.

Now, I'm having issues when **rebooting** the shuttle PC, but **only when running from the SD Card**.

- **CASE 1**: If the system is turned off, turning it on with either the SD Card or the USB Stick plugged in works perfectly.
- **CASE 2**: If the system is turned on, and a reboot command is issued (this includes `sudo reboot` (with and without the `--force` flag), `sudo shutdown -r now` and `sudo init 6`):
- **CASE 2.1**: If it was running on the **USB Stick**, it reboots just fine and I get back to the login prompt.
- **CASE 2.2**: If it was running on the **SD Card,** it shuts down fine, but **when actually turning on again it shows the BIOS splash, but after that it gets stuck on a black screen with a blinking cursor**.

In this last situation described, I have no input at all (I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, etc). However, if at this point I shut down the shuttle, and turn it on, it works perfectly (as described in **CASE 1**).

Here's what I've tried:

- Enabled all kinds of grub flags, namely those of the form
  `reboot=xxx` where `xxx` can be `bios`, `acpi`, etc... with no different
  results achieved.
- Enabled all kinds of verbose flags but all I get is the blinking
  cursor on a black screen.
- I've tried extracting the SD card from the shuttle right after
  getting the blinking cursor with the hope to extract a useful log,
  but it seems like no new logs are generated in either
  `/var/log/boot.log` or `/var/log/dmesg`.
- I've made sure that the SD card is the only bootable media selected
  in the BIOS boot order
- I've checked for potential BIOS options that could be causing
  trouble, to no avail.

I'm very confused because I don't understand what the difference is between turning off and turning on the shuttle (**CASE 1**, which works fine both using the USB and SD) and issuing a reboot command (**CASE 2**, which when using the SD card as described in **CASE 2.2** fails).

I appreciate any help I can get to figure this one out, and will provide any information as required.